# How do I add xlookup add-in for excel 2019

Tags: excel, function, excel-addins, excel-2019

My current version of Excel 2019 is v16.29.1 and I'm having difficulty with adding the add-in ExcelDNA.XFunctions64.xll i.e trying to add the function XLOOKUP. I've downloaded this file from the following link https://github.com/Excel-DNA/XFunctions/releases/tag/v0.2-alpha however, with my current version of excel I can't seem to browse locally and install the file. Is there anyway around this or is there another option other than Office365 or paying for this plugin?

Kind regards